# How to access updated element after changing it using one way binding

Tags: angular, angular2-databinding

I want to update content of a `div` using string interpolation and then access some properties of that `div` element immediately. how do i access an updated element?

In the below code snippet, how do i access updated properties of `div` element in `someEventOccurred()` method?

Here is my **component.js** file ([stackblitz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvkdpt))

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div #message>{{ data }}</div>`
})
export class AppComponent  {
  data = 'default';
  @ViewChild('message', {static: false}) message;

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.someEventOccurred();
    }, 1000);
  }

  someEventOccurred() {
    this.data = 'hello world';

    // how to run something here only after #message is updated
    console.log(this.message.nativeElement.innerText);

    setTimeout(() => {
      // this runs after 1 second, meanwhile view has been updated
      console.log(this.message.nativeElement.innerText);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

I know i can access the updated element in `ngAfterViewChecked()`, but how would i know which element has changed?
I also want to know if there is any other solution than using this hook.

Note: the above code snippet is just an example, in my real project, i'll be calling `someEventOccurred()` when i get an http response from a remote server. innerText is also just an example, i'll be using different properties of an element.

Comment: Based on the comments in your code, it sounds like you want to subscribe to an elements attribute. Is that correct?

Comment: @robbieAreBest yes, i want to subscribe to `scrollHeight` property so i can set it to `scrollTop` in order to scroll to bottom when a new content is added to the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the updated properties immediately, instead of using `setTimeout`, you can **manually** trigger **change detection**.

```js
constructor (private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

someEventOccurred () {
   this.data = 'hello world';

   this.cdr.detectChanges();

   console.log(this.message.nativeElement.innerText); // hello world
}
```

You might also find [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) about **change detection** useful.

Another approach that shouldn't involve the `ChangeDetectorRef` API would be use a component and pass data as **@Input params**. This way, you can opt for the `OnPush` detection strategy for that component and emit events(through `@Output` properties) after computation has been done internally. You can detect changes of `@Input` properties in the [`OnChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) lifecycle hook.

Comment: thanks. a question though, when would the second approach using component be better than using `ChangeDetectorRef`? or it's just our preference?

Comment: IMO, if you can avoid using `cdr` without making too much effort, then put away `cdr`. In this case I'd go with the second approach as this will allow to encapsulate the logic. For example, a parent of such component might only be interested in a few properties from the child, and computation logic can take place in the child, without adding _unrelated_ code to the parent.